# How to query custom post then display sections by meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, metabox

This seems like an easy thing to do but I am missing something here.  I have a custom post type called "recipient" and a meta check box called "`yes_current`" - (we help children with cancer and run events for them so we need to know who is a current recipient and who is a past recipient.) We want to display two sections on our RECIPIENT page: CURRENT RECIPIENTS and PAST RECIPIENTS.

My thought is to query the loop to get all of the `custom_post_types` that equal recipient, then display the featured image for all CURRENT recipients (if yes_current is ON) in the Current section, then do the same for PAST recipients in the Past section.

Thank you guys!

CODE:

```
<h1>CURRENT Recipients</h1>

<?php $current_loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'recipient', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'yes_current' => 'on'));

if( $current_loop->have_posts() ): while( $current_loop->have_posts() ): $current_loop-the_post(); 

<?php get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<h1>PAST Recipients</h1>

<?php $current_loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'recipient', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'yes_current' => 'off'));

if( $current_loop->have_posts() ): while( $current_loop->have_posts() ): $current_loop->the_post(); 

<?php get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

### Edit

Custom post meta code:

```
$meta_boxes[] = array( 'id' => 'yes_current', 'title' => 'Current Recipient', 'pages' => array( 'recipient' ), 'context' => 'side', 'priority' => 'low', 'fields' => array( array( 'name' => 'Current Recipient', 'id' => "{$prefix}yes_current", 'type' => 'checkbox', // Value can be 0 or 1 'std' => 1, ), ),
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I'm curious why you just copied/pasted the code from my answer into your question? If that code works for you, just mark the answer as correct (via the checkmark); otherwise, it is more helpful to see your *own* current code, and an explanation of what's not working correctly with it.

Comment: I didn't. Kaiser asked me to put my code up and that's what I was doing while your answer was coming in.  Neither work just yet.

Comment: Oh, never mind; we just used very similar variable names. :)

Comment: Where is `$prefix` defined for the custom post meta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Since I am using Meta Boxes from the guys at Deluxe Blog Tips, I used their helper function that replaces get_post_meta.  Here is the final code to display a list of CURRENT recipients and a list of PAST recipients for my custom_post_type Recipients.  The meta box being compared to value is rec_yes_current:

```
<h1>Current Recipients</h1>
<?php /* Start loop */ ?>
<?php $linkposts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'recipient', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));
  while ($linkposts->have_posts()) : $linkposts->the_post(); 
  $linkvalue = $linkposts->ID;
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($linkvalue), 'post-thumbnail' );
    $medical = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'rec_medical', true);
$twitter = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'rec_twitter', true);
$facebook = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'rec_facebook', true);
$dob = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'rec_dob', true);
    $today = date("m/d/Y");
    list($m,$d,$y) = explode('/',$dob);
    list($tm,$td,$ty) = explode('/',$today);
$year=$ty-$y;
    $current = rwmb_meta( 'rec_yes_current' ); 
?>

<?php  // if is current
if($current == '') {
echo '<div class="single recipient">';
echo '<p class="recname"><a href="' . get_permalink($linkvalue) . '">' . get_the_title($linkvalue) . '</a></p>';
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($linkvalue) . '" class="frame">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($linkvalue, 'thumbnail') . '</a>';
echo '<p class="year"><strong>Age</strong>: ' . $year . ' years old</p>';
echo '<p class="condition"><strong>Conditions</strong>:' . $medical . '</p>';       
echo '<p class="readmore"><a href="' . get_permalink($linkvalue) . '">read more</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
}; ?>

<h1>Past Recipients</h1>

<?php  // if is current
if($current != '') {
    echo '<div class="single recipient">';
    echo '<p class="recname"><a href="' . get_permalink($linkvalue) . '">' . get_the_title($linkvalue) . '</a></p>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($linkvalue) . '" class="frame">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($linkvalue, 'thumbnail') . '</a>';
echo '<p class="year"><strong>Age</strong>: ' . $year . ' years old</p>';
echo '<p class="condition"><strong>Conditions</strong>:' . $medical . '</p>';       
echo '<p class="readmore"><a href="' . get_permalink($linkvalue) . '">read more</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
}; ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

If there is a cleaner/better way to write this, I would love to see it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend executing two separate queries, each one differing from the other via a `meta_query` against your post custom meta key value.

```
$current_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipient',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'yes_current',
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$current_query = new WP_Query( $current_query_args );

if ( $current_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $current_query->have_posts() ) : $current_query->the_post();

    // Loop goes here

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

$past_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipient',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'yes_current',
            'value' => 'off',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$past_query = new WP_Query( $past_query_args );

if ( $past_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $past_query->have_posts() ) : $past_query->the_post();

    // Loop goes here

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks Chip. Where you have "Loop goes here", I put in: the_title() just to see if anything would get returned and nothing has.

Comment: Okay, the issue is probably the `meta_query`. What is the *exact* name of the meta key, and what is the *exact value* for the meta value (i.e. is it Boolean `true`/`false`, is it a string `'true'`/`'false'` or `'yes'`/`'no'`, or something else)?

Comment: Chip, it is a checkbox and it is called yes_current with a value of 0 or 1

Comment: And when you save it, what does it look like in your `update_post_meta()` call? Because if you're saving as Boolean `true`/`false`, then the `meta_query` should be correct.

Comment: Oh, your example code uses **`'on'`** and **`'off'`**. See updated answer.

Comment: I made the changes but nothing is showing. To be clear, should this code be inside the main loop or can these two loops be standalone?

Comment: Oh, definitely do **not** this code inside the main Loop. :) Again, to be certain of how the custom post meta data are being stored in the database: can you post your custom post meta-handling code, including the `save_post` callback (which is probably the most important part for this issue)?

Comment: Hey Chip, after looking at the meta_box creation code I noticed a prefix of rec_ which I added to your code and still nothing is showing.  Here is that meta_box code:
   
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id' => 'yes_current',
'title' => 'Current Recipient',
'pages' => array( 'recipient' ),
'context' => 'side',
'priority' => 'low',
'fields' => array(
 array(
 'name' => 'Current Recipient',
 'id'   => "{$prefix}yes_current",
 'type' => 'checkbox',
 // Value can be 0 or 1
 'std'  => 1,
 ),
),

Comment: I added that to your OP, but that's not actually where the meta boxes get created, or the meta data saved to the DB. That's just an array...

Comment: Chip, sorry :) this part is a little over my head.  Maybe this helps: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/helper-function-to-get-meta-value/ - it is the plugin code I used to create the meta boxes.

Comment: Thanks, but we need to see *your own* code. Are the meta boxes defined in your Theme, or in a Plugin, or what? What I'm really looking for is the callback function that includes this code: **`update_post_meta( $post->ID, '($prefix)yes_current', $somevalue )`**.